# Looping nodes in with cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodes, cytoscape.js

I am currently trying to do looping for a graph by using cytoscape.js
The problem is I don't quite get how to do it since there are some repeating nodes.

I have these data like this :

```
Sheraton Cherry, Rosaceae, Dentate, Pinnate
Pineapple Guava, Myrtaceae, Entire, Pinnate
Chinese Sumac, Rosaceae, Entire, Pinnate
```

And as you can see some data is repeating.

So far this is what I got :

```
  elements: {
nodes: [
  { data: { id: 'a', name: 'Sheraton Cherry' } },
  { data:  { id: 'a1', name: 'Rosacea'}},
  { data: { id: 'a2', name: 'Dentate' } },
  { data: { id: 'a3', name: 'Pinnate' } },
  { data: { id: 'b', name: 'Pineapple Guava' } },
  { data:  { id: 'b1', name: 'Myrtaceae'}},
  { data: { id: 'b2', name: 'Entire' } },
  { data: { id: 'a3', name: 'Pinnate' } }

],
edges: [
  { data: { source: 'a1', target: 'a' }},
  { data: { source: 'a2', target: 'a' }},
  { data: { source: 'a3', target: 'a' }},
  { data: { source: 'b1', target: 'b'}},
  { data: { source: 'b2', target: 'b'}},
  { data: { source: 'a3', target: 'b'}}
]
```

},

I typed it manually in which the graph came out perfectly but since this is only some of the data and I have 10 more of it, I should loop the nodes and edges.

But how can I do it?

Found something like this :

```js
var demoNodes = [];
var demoEdges = [];

demoNodes.push({

    data: {
        id: b[0],
        name:b[0]
    }
});

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    demoNodes.push({

        data: {
            id: a[i],
            name:a[i]
        }
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    demoEdges.push({
        data: {
            source: b[0],
            target: a[i]
        }
    })
}
```

but still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Parse your input data and convert it to the [elements JSON format](http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/elements-json).

If your data is just comma separated, use `.split()` and `.trim()` on the input string.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Cytoscape does not allow elements with duplicate IDs, but it would be better in principle if you disallow duplicates as you parse (or with another pass post parsing).

Comment: May I know what is pass post parsing? 
Is it possible to arrange my data into nodes and edges manually since I cannot eliminate the duplicates.